# Spring docs imply @EnableRetry and @Retryable work with spring's feign client. But it doesn't seem to

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign, spring-retry

In the spring docs [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_retrying-failed-requests.html), it is suggested that adding Spring Retry as a dependency will allow us to enable it on a Spring Feign client.

However, when I try the below code:

```
@Component
@FeignClient(value = "myFeign", url = "${my.url}")
public interface ingestionInterface{
    @Retryable(
            value = {FeignException.class},
            backoff = @Backoff(delay=50000)
    )
    @RequestMapping(
            produces = "application/json",
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
    Optional<ResponseEntity<Response>> postRequest(@Valid @RequestBody Request request);
}
```

My application won't compile, with the error:

`Bean named 'blah.blah.ingestionInterface' is expected to be of type 'blah.blah.ingestionInterface' but was actually of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy143'`

If this is not the way to use Spring Retry with Spring Feign, how is it meant to be used?

Comment: Are you trying to retry on socket timeouts or server exceptions? Feign supports retries in both cases.

Comment: we used ribbon in the end

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this article](https://engineering.getmidas.com/using-spring-retryable-with-feign-client-methods-9f77e509ad55) could help you. There is a bit of custom work but it works around Proxy problem